# How do I find the parameter type of a function implementing certain interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, dom, typescript2.0

For example, I have a

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>   
</form>
```

I need to implement the handdleSubmit funciton. Therefore, I do

```
 handleSubmit(event:any) {
      this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
 }
```

For the type of a parameter I do not know, I always put any on it. Is there a way to find the type of the passing parameter instead of putting any?

Answer (score 1):

Dom events are defined in [lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts), see WindowEventMap, GlobalEventHandlersEventMap, WindowEventHandlersEventMap

```
interface GlobalEventHandlersEventMap {
    "abort": UIEvent;
    "animationcancel": AnimationEvent;
    .....
    "submit": Event;
    .....
    "waiting": Event;
    "wheel": WheelEvent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define type of event type is `SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement>` instead of `any`, Reactjs `BaseSyntheticEvent` type has been defined in `@types/react/index.d.ts`, if you have a good IDE,  easy to find it (ex: ctrl + click) and the IDE will auto suggest function or property what you can use with your `event` param.

Comment: I am using VS code. The ctrl + click did nothing. Which IDE has this function? Thanks!